# Looping several setTimeout() functions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, settimeout

I have succesed to make my animation where i'm changing the size of the div´s with a setTimeout. The problem is, that i can't find a way for them to loop, i´ve tried to call to start() function within the function itself, but after the first execution, the animation gets really messy. Can someone help me with making the whole sequence loop without any trouble?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('Sådan!');
});


function div1ind() {
    $(function () {
        $('#div1').css({
            'z-index': 2
        })
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#div1').animate({
            height: '1080px',
            width: '1918px',
            top: '0px',
            left: '0px'
        }, 500);
    });

}

function div1ud() {

    $(function () {
        $('#div1').animate({
            height: '540px',
            width: '959px',
            top: '0px',
            left: '0px'
        }, 500);

    });



    $(function () {
        $('#div1').css({
            'z-index': 1
        })
    });
}

function div2ind() {

    $(function () {
        $('#div2').css({
            'z-index': 2
        })
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#div2').animate({
            height: '1080px',
            width: '1918px',
            top: '0px',
            left: '0px'
        }, 500);
    });


}



function div2ud() {

    $(function () {
        $('#div2').animate({
            height: '540px',
            width: '959px',
            top: '0px',
            left: '959px'
        }, 500);

    });


    $(function () {
        $('#div2').css({
            'z-index': 1
        })
    });
}

function div3ind() {

    $(function () {
        $('#div3').css({
            'z-index': 2
        })
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#div3').animate({
            height: '1080px',
            width: '1918px',
            top: '0px',
            left: '0px'
        }, 500);
    });

}

function div3ud() {

    $(function () {
        $('#div3').animate({
            height: '540px',
            width: '959px',
            top: '540px',
            left: '0px'
        }, 500);

    });

    $(function () {
        $('#div3').css({
            'z-index': 1
        })
    });
}

function div4ind() {

    $(function () {
        $('#div4').css({
            'z-index': 2
        })
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#div4').animate({
            height: '1080px',
            width: '1918px',
            top: '0px',
            left: '0px'
        }, 500);
    });
}

function div4ud() {

    $(function () {
        $('#div4').animate({
            height: '540px',
            width: '959px',
            top: '540px',
            left: '959px'
        }, 500);

    });


    $(function () {
        $('#div4').css({
            'z-index': 1
        })
    });
}

function start() {

    $(function () {
        setTimeout('div1ind()', 2000);
        setTimeout('div1ud()', 4000);
        setTimeout('div2ind()', 6000);
        setTimeout('div2ud()', 8000);
        setTimeout('div3ind()', 10000);
        setTimeout('div3ud()', 12000);
        setTimeout('div4ind()', 14000);
        setTimeout('div4ud()', 16000);
    });
}

start();
```

Comment: you don't need to use `$(function(){` to wrap every function. Use it once and wrap everything

Comment: Then the functions will all execute at once, and i dont want that. That why seperated them and used setTimeout, does that make sense...? Im a bit new to jquery...

Comment: If i use setInterval, then i can loop them yes, but how can i plan the order and time between my functions at the same time...?

Comment: @user2469206 `$(function () {` stands for `$(document).ready(function () {` so they will all run when the DOM is ready.

Comment: @Spokey: Only the one inside the `start` function will actually bind the `ready` event, the rest will be called after the event has already happened, so jQuery will just call the event handlers immediately.

Comment: @user2469206 - Would you mind looking at the solutions provided to you and selecting one or commenting on them?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a better case for setInterval, so as to prevent race conditions with multiple timeout instances.

The added benefit to a solution like this is that you can easily add or remove function calls to your list without reprogramming and double-checking all the timeouts.

What I'm doing here is creating an array that maps to your other functions, and then setting an interval that will trigger every 2 seconds.  The interval increments the value of i, and calls the function that is the modulus of i % x (where x is the number of functions in your list).

(Edit: tweaked the code to be neater.  Edit 2: wrapped in an anonymous function to prevent calling the same index.)

```
var i = 0;
var function_map = [div1ind, div1ud, div2ind, div2ud, div3ind, div3ud, div4in, div4ud];    
window.setInterval(function() {
    function_map[i++ % function_map.length]()
}, 2000);
```

**EDIT**: Per your comment below, if you want them to have different delays, you could do this (add the timeout into the function map and build a recursive timeout chain):

```
var i = 0;
var function_map = [
    [1000,div1ind], 
    [2000,div1ud], 
    [3000,div2ind], 
    [2000,div2ud], 
    [5000,div3ind], 
    [3000,div3ud], 
    [4000,div4in], 
    [2000,div4ud]
];
function start() {    
    var func = function_map[i++ % function_map.length];
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        func[1]();
        start();
    }, func[0]);
}
start();
```

Comment: There can't be any multiple threads, as Javascript is strictly single threaded. Every event is handled in the same thread.

Comment: An interval waits for each process to complete before sleeping and beginning the next in the chain.  A series of timeouts does not function the same way.  Each timeout is independent of the others, and thus functions similarly to a series of threads, regardless of the fact that JS is single-threaded.

Comment: There can only be one event handler running at a time, so how would a timeout *not* wait for the previous handler to complete?

Comment: Run this and you'll see what I mean.  It waits while the loop executes, then logs 1 and 2 one immediately after the other.  `function test1() {for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {/* wait */} console.log('1');} function test2() {console.log('2');} setTimeout(test1, 1000); setTimeout(test2, 2000);`

Comment: An interval, on the other hand, would maintain a *n* second interval between the two function calls.

Comment: I see what you mean, but there are no functions here that take any long time to execute.

Comment: Maybe, but it's still a good habit to develop.  If you wanted to do this with `setTimeout`, the proper way would be to have some recursion in `start()` that sets a timeout for an anonymous function calling a single function in the chain followed by a call to `start()` to trigger the next timeout in the chain.

Comment: What do you mean by "maybe"? What function do you mean could take a long time to run?

Comment: thanks for all the answers. It´s a very clever one, use window.setInterval, but the problem is, that in the final version, they will not have the same interval length. I got this one to work (almost):function start(){
 clearTimeout();
 setTimeout('div1ind()', 2000);
 setTimeout('div1ud()', 4000);
 setTimeout('div2ind()', 8000);
 setTimeout('div2ud()', 10000);
 setTimeout('div3ind()', 14000);
 setTimeout('div3ud()', 16000);
 setTimeout('div4ind()', 20000);
 setTimeout('div4ud()', 22000);
}

setInterval('start()',24000);

Comment: but the odd thing is, that only in the first run, my animations run smoothly, in the loops, they behave odd, fx. the z-index on some div's execute before the animation, so it animates behind the other divs...

Comment: @Guffa - By "maybe", I mean "maybe in this instance, but not in every instance," thus explaining why consideration of execution time is a good habit to develop.  It's an American colloquialism.

Comment: @user2469206 - Edited to show you how to use this solution with variable timeout lengths.

Comment: Thanks Steven, it´s working :) I still got the animation issues after the first run...maybe you have an idea of how i can fix that?

Comment: @user2469206 - Can you be more specific about the issues you're having?

Comment: @user2469206 - If you're getting choppiness, you may have issues with animation stacks overlapping each other.  You could use the `jquery.animation()` parameter `complete` to define a callback that will allow you to trigger the next animation in your series only when the first one has completed.

Comment: I figured out, that it all has to do with the z-index. I´m trying to reset the z-index after every div has animated, but it wont work :( so the first run works great (in the css they are all set to z-index:1), then in the loops, div1 animates behind the others, and div4 is on top eventhough i told the code otherwise :(

Answer (score 1):

Your `setTimeout` calls makes the functions start at different times, so make another that makes the `start` function start again:

```
function start() {
  setTimeout(div1ind, 2000);
  setTimeout(div1ud, 4000);
  setTimeout(div2ind, 6000);
  setTimeout(div2ud, 8000);
  setTimeout(div3ind, 10000);
  setTimeout(div3ud, 12000);
  setTimeout(div4ind, 14000);
  setTimeout(div4ud, 16000);
  setTimeout(start, 18000);
}
```

Don't use `$(function(){ ... })` everywhere, that is a shorthand for `$.ready(function(){ ... })`, i.e. it would bind the `ready` event. However, if you do that after the `ready` event has occured, jQuery will just call the callback immediately, so it's just useless code.

Bind the `ready` event once to start the `start` function, and remove that extra wrappers from all your functions. Instead of:

```
start();
```

use this to use the `start` function as callback for the `ready` event handler:

```
$(start);
```

or the equivalent:

```
$(document).ready(start);
```

Comment: This won't work as intended.  You'll get a 4 second delay at the end, instead of a 2 second delay.  Better to use interval to prevent race conditions, anyway.

Comment: @StevenMoseley: Just adjust the time to get the intended effect. Regarding race conditions, as Javscript is strictly single threaded, there can never ever be any multiple threads.

Comment: Each timeout operates on its own timer.  Even though they're operating in a single thread, if one of the timeout callbacks takes longer, you'll get inconsistent intervals in between each timeout.  Not a true race condition, but the effect is similar.

Comment: @StevenMoseley: Timing isn't exact, but how do you think using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` would make that any better?